Define different clearance foriInternal and external layers in Altium
In an Altium pcb I need to implement this clearance scheme:

default clearance: 0.15mm
Nets belonging to "HV" class, on internal layers: 0.2mm
Nets belonging to "HV" class, on external layers: 0.4mm

I get everything working fine using this rule:

Where the first object matches: InNetClass('HV')

and (simplifying) one of these rules:

Where the second object matches: OnOutside
Where the second object matches: OnTopLayer
Where the second object matches: OnLayer('top')

But there's a problem. In Altium vias and pads are on layer "Multi-Layer", therefore they are not in the in the scope of the forementioned commands OnOutside, OnTopLayer, OnLayer('top'). The result is that "HV" polygons apply the default clearance of 0.15mm with non "HV" vias and pads.
Said in other words: a non "HV" via in the middle of a "HV" polygon should have 0.2mm clearance on inner layers and 0.4mm clearance on outer layers, but the result is 0.15mm clearance.
How can I define different clearance for internal and external layers, including vias and pads?

Right, so just include them in the query too. :)
Note that precedence matters, so, if those objects need to match multiple rules, those other rules should probably be earlier, and the objects queried in the "second" class.  When an object matches the "first" query, it's removed from subsequent checks, which can make for weirdness (like interactive routing / show clearances to display incorrectly, and routing and checking to fail, or at least behave in a non-obvious manner).  The larger-clearance rule needs higher precedence, of course (otherwise, what else would set pad-to-pad clearance?).
For example, I have such a query in a design here,

for the mid rule, replace OnOutside with OnMid.  There is a similar rule pair, higher up, for another net class (the net classes are exclusive so there are no objects being double-ruled here), and a few for specific (very narrow) cases, certain object types/sizes, at the highest precedence (thus those rules remove the respective "first" objects from further checks).
The precedence stuff is a bit obtuse to describe (and I haven't put much effort into phrasing it at all well here), but it is logical once you understand it.  Reading the Altium docs will prove illuminating here.
